# what's the simplest benchmark for recurrent neural networks?

Tags: machine-learning, lstm

i am exploring new architectures for LSTMs. i have looked into a few commonly used datasets, such as IMDB's movie reviews and sine waves, but haven't found a good generalizable dataset. if MNIST is the "hello world" for convolutional networks, then what would be the equivalent dataset for LSTMs?

Answer (score 2):

You can check examples in which people use simpler models, like HMM and try running LSTM on them.

For example you can try running [this POS tagging code](https://github.com/lazyprogrammer/machine_learning_examples/tree/master/nlp_class2) (the `pos_*` part) from lazyprogrammer's course (here is [a script](https://github.com/lambdaofgod/machine_learning_examples/blob/py3-scripts/nlp_class2/get_data.sh) that downloads and handles the data). This code contains models that use LSTMs on Tensorflow/Theano and also HMMs (and even logistic regression that does not take into account the sequential nature of the data).